# Querying DynamoDB global secondary index with values IN a list

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, partiql

I have a DynamoDB table with many attributes and a global_secondary_index defined on one of them.
This table contains millions of items, and I need to do a query which on SQL would be something like:
*Select * from table where field1 is IN (value1,..., valuen)*. *field1* is the indexed one.

Note:

- I have 10k value to check in the IN
- I don't want to scan the table, but use the global secondary index

So far I have not been able to find any easy way to do that, either via DynamoDB AWS console or via the AWS programmatic API.

I have noticed that PartiQL offers such syntax, and I am curious if it does a table scan under the hood or just fetch the items one by one. (Anyway, PartiQL is currently not available for me)

As a workaround, I did a script to return the items one by one.

I have read such post, which does not help here: [Querying DynamoDB with a partition key and list of specific sort keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469036/querying-dynamodb-with-a-partition-key-and-list-of-specific-sort-keys#answer-50471503)

**Finally** I would also be curious to understand possibly **why such feature does not exist natively** (what are the technical constraints if any)?

Thanks

Comment: Ouch, that is one painful query. Is it a different, arbitrary set of up to 10k values each time or is it more predictable and hence something you could pre-label and store in a new attribute (e.g. via DynamoDB Streams trigger)? Alternatively, are you open to using Elasticsearch or equivalent in this solution?

Comment: It is just one shot actually. Just to extract specific items matching. No, actually I would like a pure DynamoDB solution (web console or API), and possibly get some insights related to this with PartiQL.

Answer (score 1):

PartiQL will be broken up into individual Query operations under the hood. However, because it needs to keep a pointer to the LastEvaluatedKey then it must do each Query operation sequentially. That means that it is a slower operation than firing 10k Async requests to DynamoDB on your own.

The limit of number of values in the `IN` clause is 50. So a maximum of 50 keys, which can return 0-N items each.

You can use an IAM policy which will [prevent PartiQL from conducting a Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-iam.html#access-policy-ql-iam-example6), which will safeguard you from writing a bad PartiQL Query.

Be sure to set your index explicitly, DynamoDB does not have a SQL optimiser.

Comment: Thanks, apart from PartiQL is there any other way with the programmatic api to support an IN so I  don't have to loop myself?

Comment: No, PartiQL is the only API that supports IN and it still be efficient. If you wanted to use another API you would have to use a FilterExpression which is not efficient as you must also pay to evaluate items which do not match your expression.

Comment: Thanks, my question was not only focused on PartiQL, but also to understand why this does not exist natively?

Comment: Mostly because DynamoDB tries to eliminate unbounded work. That's why there's a limit on batch APIs, why there is a max page size of 1MB etc...

Answer (score 0):

The way PartQL would do the following

```
Select * 
from "ddbTable"."mygsi"
where field1 is IN (value1, value2)
```

Is simply that behind the scenes it basically ends up as two queries to DDB.

I can't find any documented limit with a quick search, but I suspect that 10K values would be outside that limit.

The thing to understand is that a Query in DDB can only touch 1 partition.  A "table scan" is broken into individual scans of each partition; [sequentially by default but can be done in parallel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.ParallelScan)

Also that a GSI is basically just a separate DDB table with slightly different rules (duplicate Primary Keys allowed) than the main table.

So in short, you need to write some code that would loop through the 10K values and run a query of the GSI for each value.